# Docker ate up all my disk space

Tags: docker

I played with docker all day and finally I ran out of disk space.

```
docker ps
docker images
docker volume ls
```

All this commands show me nothing (I delete all images, containers and volumes). 
But there is still no space at all.

Did missed something ? (I am sure docker is guilty for this=), at the morning there was 100 GB free space)
p.s. I am on OSx

### Update

I freed the space by deleting docker-machine

```
docker-machine rm default
```

I believe, it is not a brilliant solution, what would I do if it was linux environment ? =) 
So any suggestion by keeping docker away from eating disk space would be great.

Comment: `docker ps -a` will show the containers that are not running. Delete those as well.

Comment: hi, docker ps -a shows me nothing

Comment: @IgorSamusenko: Please refer to my answer which consists solution for linux, as well as Mac OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete all the images that are not used by any active containers (stopped containers are still active!):

```
docker images | grep -i none | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Delete all docker images (not necessarily recommended but clearly better than deleting the host, which is what your docker-machine thing did :)):

```
docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Comment: once docker ate all the space docker daemon would not start after reboot

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure, that it has happened because of docker, then you can try below commands:

On Linux:

```
service docker stop
rm -rf /var/lib/docker ( the default graphdriver which you have set)
service docker start
```

NOTE: It would remove all your images and containers.

On Mac:

```
docker-machine ls
docker-machine kill <machine-name> #to kill machine 
docker-machine rm <machine-name>   #to remove machine
```

Comment: I dont have "service" I am on OSX

Comment: Then you can `docker-machine ls` to see all docker VM running. 
And kill or remove any machine by `docker-machine kill <machine-name>` or `docker-machine rm <machine-name>` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

`docker system prune` gets rid of all Docker components that are dangling, such as images or networks that are not named and not part of a running container.

Answer (score 0):

Docker use /var/lib/docker folder to store the layers. There are ways to reclaim the space and move the storage to some other directory.

You can mount a bigger disk space and move the content of /var/lib/docker to the new mount location and make sym link.

There is detail explanation on how to do above task.

http://www.scmtechblog.net/2016/06/clean-up-docker-images-from-local-to.html

You can remove the intermediate layers too.

https://github.com/vishalvsh1/docker-image-cleanup

```
##Removing Dangling images
##There are the layers images which are being created during building docker image. This is a great way to recover the spaces used by old and unused layers.

docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)

##If you do not want to remove all container you can have filter for days and weeks old like below
docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep "days ago" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm
docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep "weeks ago" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm

##Removing stopped container
docker ps -a | grep Exited | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm
```